# In xamarin shared F# project modules are marked as "Not defined" on Console project

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio, xamarin, f#

I wanna use shared project. It work fine for the iOS/Android project. Now I wanna create a console project for do the unit testing.

However, despite in the editor the modules are found and the intellisense work for them, when compiled I get:

```
..Test/TestsClient.fs(6,6): Error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Db' is not defined. (FS0039) (Test)
```

And others like that.

I have target .NET 4.6.2 and tested too with 4.5.

This is the project:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">iPhoneSimulator</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{90334D33-1842-4D13-8367-069308850F4E}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Cobros</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Test</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|iPhoneSimulator' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <ExternalConsole>true</ExternalConsole>
    <GenerateTailCalls>true</GenerateTailCalls>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|iPhoneSimulator' ">
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants></DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <ExternalConsole>true</ExternalConsole>
    <GenerateTailCalls>true</GenerateTailCalls>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\FSharp\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '10.0' OR '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '11.0'">
    <FSharpTargetsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\..\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0\Microsoft.FSharp.Targets</FSharpTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.ValueTuple">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ValueTuple.4.3.0\lib\netstandard1.0\System.ValueTuple.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Fuchu">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Fuchu.1.0.3.0\lib\Fuchu.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="FSharp.Core">
      <HintPath>..\packages\FSharp.Core.4.2.1\lib\net45\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="Mono.Data.Sqlite" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="AssemblyInfo.fs" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <Compile Include="TestUtils.fs" />
    <Compile Include="TestsClient.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="..\CobrosDb.projitems" Label="Shared" Condition="Exists('..\CobrosDb.projitems')" />
  <Import Project="$(FSharpTargetsPath)" />
</Project>
```

This is the build log:

```
Target GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
  Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Target CoreCompile:
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/fsharp/fsc.exe -o:obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/Test.exe
    -g
    --debug:full
    --noframework
    --define:DEBUG
    --optimize-
    --tailcalls-
    -r:.../Movil/packages/FSharp.Core.4.2.1/lib/net45/FSharp.Core.dll
    -r:.../Movil/packages/Fuchu.1.0.3.0/lib/Fuchu.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/mscorlib.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Core.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Data.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Numerics.dll
    -r:.../Movil/packages/System.ValueTuple.4.3.0/lib/netstandard1.0/System.ValueTuple.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/System.Xml.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Collections.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ComponentModel.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Globalization.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.IO.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Linq.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Linq.Expressions.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Linq.Parallel.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Linq.Queryable.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Net.Primitives.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Net.Requests.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ObjectModel.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.Emit.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Handles.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Security.Principal.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Http.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.ServiceModel.Security.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Text.Encoding.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Threading.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Threading.Timer.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Xml.XDocument.dll
    -r:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.0.1/lib/mono/4.6.2-api/Facades/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll
    --target:exe
    --warnaserror:76
    --fullpaths
    --flaterrors
    --subsystemversion:6.00
    --highentropyva+
    /var/folders/tm/n9jvsc5s4m72hg8_r47dn4z40000gn/T/.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2.AssemblyAttributes.fs
    AssemblyInfo.fs
    TestUtils.fs
    TestsClient.fs
    Program.fs
    .../Movil/Db.fs
    .../Movil/DbClient.fs
    .../Movil/Utils.fs


    .../Movil/Test/TestsClient.fs(6,6): error FS0039: The namespace or module 'Db' is not defined.
```